# Most efficient way to filter a pivottable's row field for "(blank)" entries

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for the most efficient way (least code) to filter a row field of a pivottable for "(blank)" entries.  I know how to set a PageField / Report Filter (hopefully I am speaking correctly here) using the .CurrentPage method:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Some Field").CurrentPage = "Something"
```

To me, this is efficient, but this only works for PageFields not RowFields.  I am also aware of the loop option to set PivotItems.Visible properties as 'True' or 'False':

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Some Field")
    For each PvtItm in .PivotItems
        If pvtItm.Value = "(blank)" Then
            PvtItm.Visible = True
        Else
            PvtItm.Visible = False
        End If
End With
```

This works for RowFields but is a few extra lines.  I can use this but I was just curious if there was shorter method.  Also, I only want to see "(blank)" entries so if I need to set it a different way then using = "(blank)" I would be interested to know what to use.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you record a macro of filtering a Row Label with Label Filters > Equals... you get something like

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Some Field") _
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="(blank)" ' or maybe Value1:="" ?
```

Comment: Thanks, Slai -- that did work.  The only thing I noticed is that the slicer connected to that pivottable and field does not reflect the filter, but the pivottable itself looks good.

Comment: I tried it on Excel 2007, so you can try recording the macro on your version to see if the generated code is different.